# Как найти площадь прямоугольников с учётом пересечений (объединение прямоугольников) за O(n log n)

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

Задача:
На плоскости есть много прямоугольников. Их стороны параллельны осям координат. Нужно посчитать занимаемую ими площадь. Так же нужно учитывать то что они пересекаются. И всё бы хорошо, только прямоугольников целых 100000, а их координаты достигают 10^14 (ага, и размеры ~10^18)!

Я придумал только такое решение:
Используем метод сканирующей прямой. Сортируем по x все вертикальные стороны. Проходимся по ним, и соответственно формула при переходе прямой такая:
S_new = DELTA_X * active_ys;
Где DELTA_X - насколько переместилась сканирующая прямая, а active_ys - суммарная высота пересекающих линию прямоугольников.
И проблема как раз таки в вычислении этого active_ys. Можно сохранять все высоты прямоугольников как отрезки, и потом их складывать с учётом пересечений, но у меня это получается только за O(Y) (где Y - кол-во отрезков), и сложность всего алгоритма получается O(NY), а т.к. в худшем случае Y = N, то выходит O(N^2), что разумеется очень плохо. Можно было бы хранить все точки по y, но учитывая ограничения по координатам (10^14) ни в какую память это не влезет.
Еще была идея хранить в дереве отрезков все эти отрезки, но непонятно как их суммировать, т.к. они ведь могут и не пересекаться, и задача по сути вернётся к исходной. К тому же эти отрезки надо ещё и удалять.

Может кто-то знает как можно решить эту задачку хотя бы за O(n log n)?

Comment: возможно глупая идея, потому просто комментом напишу. У вас же проблема в том, что прямоугольники пересаются, иначе можно было бы просто все плошади сложить, так? А что если отсортировать все прямоугольники, идти слева направо, находить все пересекающиеся прямоугольники и делить их на более мелкие прямоугольники, но которые уже не пересекаются? Типа если 2 прямоугольника пересекаются, то убрать их и вместо них добавить прямоугольники (до 5 штук), но которые уже не пересекаются? Интуиция говорит, что это вроде можно за логарифм сделать, и потом за линию сложить все площади.

Comment: возможно, но мне кажется что не сработает, т.к. уже разделённые прямоугольники могут опять пересекаться с чем-нибудь, значит и для них тоже надо проводить проверку, и может так выйти что можно эти прямоугольники почти до бесконечности делить.

Comment: Заметаете прямой. Статус - [дерево отрезков](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree), которое хранит минимум числа покрытий (прямоугольниками) для точки. Такое дерево обновляется за логарифм при добалении/убавлении прямоугольника. Всего будет nlogn.

Comment: _для точки_ - если имеете ввиду каждую y-точку на прямой, то этих точек у меня примерно 10^18*2, не думаю что влезет в оперативку.

Comment: Все горизонтальные стороны прямоугольников сортируете. Получаете 2 * 10^5 - 1 отрезков на вертикальной прямой. Собираете их в дерево. При заметании вертикальной прямой добавление/удаление прямоугольника влияет на отрезки целиком, не на отдельные точки.

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.algorithmica.org/cs/decomposition/scanline/

Последний пункт статьи описывает решение этой проблемы. Дерево отрезков - решает вопрос.

[image: Фрагмент статьи]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)